# How if condition work inside location block in nginx conf?

Tags: nginx-location

```
location /x/ {

  limit_conn x 500;

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

  allow all;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

  proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

  chunked_transfer_encoding off;

  proxy_buffering off;

  proxy_cache off;

  proxy_read_timeout 2073600;

  if ($http_upgrade = websocket) {

   proxy_pass        http://x;

  }
  if ($http_upgrade != websocket) {

   proxy_pass        http://y;

  }

}
```

Here i want to make "websocket" to **case insensitive(ignore case)**.How can i make? I have tried some things myself. Like:

```
1.

if ($http_upgrade = ~*websocket) {

   proxy_pass        http://x;
  }

if ($http_upgrade != ~*websocket) {

  proxy_pass        http://y;
  }

2.

if ($http_upgrade = "(?i) websocket") {

proxy_pass        http://x;
  }

if ($http_upgrade != "(?i) websocket") {

proxy_pass        http://y;
  }
```

But both of case, these are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like these :

```
if ($http_upgrade == "websocket") 
{
    proxy_pass        http://x;
}
if ($http_upgrade != "websocket") 
{
    proxy_pass        http://y;
}
```

**OR**

```
if ($http_upgrade == "websocket") 
{
    proxy_pass        http://x;
 }
else
{
    proxy_pass        http://y;
}
```